# Modify Soap message in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have interesting task. I have two wcf
Endpoints. Each end point located in
different address.  Endpoints are not exposed
to the client . I have additional main end point
which exposed to client and only via this end point , other two end points can be invoked .
Based on some input  class I need to decide 
which end point I should invoke and in response
I need to transform return XML to response XML .

My solution is to create empty operation contract
and implement Http module that will trigger
in end request event. Based on input parameter
I will create soap request to one of the two endpoint and will transfer the result to result XML.

May be instead I should use message inspectors 
instead ? Did  you met similar problem ?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are trying to do? maybe some code examples.  Are all endpoints on a single service? can the main endpoint be a router service?  Instead of an empty operation contract, you can use Message as the parameter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734675.aspx

Comment: main endpoint is a route service . It receive tnput parameter, some complex type. Based on it it should invoke one of two endpoints that not exposed to client. Each endpoint return result XML in other format. The service should format result to one format .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to implement in Http module.
The problem is when WCF method 
return complex type , deserelization
errors were raised . Therefore I implemented
IoperationInvoker attribute .  Added in behaviour.
Based on input parameter I am invoking
maching service and desreliaze object by
my self.